# Could not initialize Report Engine server. (Error: RWI 00226) while opening WeBi Report

Tags: java, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Facing problem while opening the document.

```
reportEngines =
                (ReportEngines) enterpriseSession.getService("ReportEngines");
        ReportEngine wiRepEngine =
                (ReportEngine) reportEngines.getService(
                        ReportEngines.ReportEngineType.WI_REPORT_ENGINE);


        /*
         * Process Webi Documents from a folder
         * */

        for (Object object : infoObjects) {
            IInfoObject infoObject = (IInfoObject) object;
            String path = getInfoObjectPath(infoObject);
            if (path.startsWith("/")) {

                String doc = infoObject.getTitle();
                System.out.println("Title :" + doc + "\n ID " + infoObject.getID() );
                System.out.println(path + "/" + doc);
                System.out.println(infoObject.toString());

                DocumentInstance widoc = wiRepEngine.openDocument(infoObject.getID());

            }
        }
```

While calling openDocument() is throws following Exception

```
com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.CommunicationException: Cannot initialize Report Engine server. (Error: RWI 00226)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.occa.OccaConnection.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.occa.OccaConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.occa.OccaServerConnectionManager.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.occa.OccaReportEngineComAdapter.createCadenzaSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.occa.OccaReportEngineComAdapter.initNewCadenzaSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.occa.OccaReportEngineComAdapter.openDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.ReportEngineImpl.openDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.occa.WebiReportEngine.openDocument(Unknown Source)
    at BO_Report_Conversion.main(BO_Report_Conversion.java:69)
Caused by: com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.OCAFrameworkException$ServiceConnection: Unable to connect to service CDZHome from server SAPBI41.WebIntelligenceProcessingServer via CMS vps2tbo01.syntelorg.com:7400 (FWM 01006)
cause:com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.idl.ImplServ.OSCAFactoryPackage.connection_failure: IDL:img.seagatesoftware.com/ImplServ/OSCAFactory/connection_failure:1.0
detail:Unable to connect to service CDZHome from server SAPBI41.WebIntelligenceProcessingServer via CMS vps2tbo01.syntelorg.com:7400 (FWM 01006) IDL:img.seagatesoftware.com/ImplServ/OSCAFactory/connection_failure:1.0
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgr.getUnmanagedService(ServiceMgr.java:864)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.AbstractStubHelper.getService(AbstractStubHelper.java:29)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedService.validate(ManagedService.java:781)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSession.validateStatelessService(ManagedSession.java:610)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSession.newService(ManagedSession.java:911)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSession.get(ManagedSession.java:300)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSessions.get(ManagedSessions.java:297)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgr.getManagedService(ServiceMgr.java:697)
    at com.businessobjects.rebean.wi.occa.OccaConnection$CDZStubHelper.getService(Unknown Source)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedService.validate(ManagedService.java:781)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSession.validateStatelessService(ManagedSession.java:610)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSession.newService(ManagedSession.java:911)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSession.get(ManagedSession.java:273)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ManagedSessions.get(ManagedSessions.java:297)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgr.getManagedService(ServiceMgr.java:697)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.idl.ImplServ.OSCAFactoryPackage.connection_failure: IDL:img.seagatesoftware.com/ImplServ/OSCAFactory/connection_failure:1.0
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.idl.ImplServ.OSCAFactoryPackage.connection_failureHelper.read(connection_failureHelper.java:102)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.idl.ImplServ._OSCAFactoryStub.newService(_OSCAFactoryStub.java:92)
    at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgr.getUnmanagedService(ServiceMgr.java:845)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to execute XI3 code in BI4.1?

Comment: No i am not trying to execute XI3 code

Comment: But you are in BI4.1?  I saw that error when I tried to run my (working) XI3 in BI4.1.  There were a bunch of additional jars that needed to be imported.

Comment: I can see an error  "Caused by: com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.OCAFrameworkException$ServiceConnection: Unable to connect to service CDZHome from server SAPBI41.WebIntelligenceProcessingServer via CMS. Please check  the status of Webintelligence processing server & connection server in CMC. And also please take out server details from error logs as it might raise a security concern.

Comment: I have the same issue, but in my case I am definitely using XI3 code. (I am testing it on BO4 to see, whats changes are needed). My aim is to create an application that runs on both versions. I added all BO4 jars, but still get this error. Have there been other changes?

Comment: Do we need to add additional jars when we are doing with BO 4.1? Did anyone got to know how to fix this issue?